# Why did Teresa know Thomas's and her name?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

How did Teresa know Thomas's name when she wakes up in the lift in *The Maze Runner*, and how did she remember her own name when the others couldn't?

Comment: Perhaps girls are effected differently by whatever drug is used to suppress the memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her name, she just remembered earlier than everyone else. While the others used to take days to remember, her name came in hours or minutes.

Could be also, since she was working for the wicked, that she just took a smaller portion of whatever they were working with to erase the memory.

Now Thomas's name, I think she just had dreams/visions about him, just like Thomas had visions/dreams about her.

Comment: I have realised that Teresa went into the Glade with her full memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the book, it explains that right before she wakes up from her coma she remembers stuff and telepathically (through Thomas's mind) says to him everything she remembers, her name, Thomas´s name, and more.